# Display Stores by Region with relations

Tags: relations

I need display Stores by Region, by example:

- **Alabama**

  - Store X
  - Store Y
- **Idaho**

  - Store A
  - Store B

So:

- I create two channels **Stores** and **Regions**.
- In the channel **Stores** I create a **entries field type** called **storesRegion** and check **Regions** source.

[image: craft control panel]

So great! I can create new stores and select where the store is located.

[image]

I can display the Regions like this:

```
{% set relatedRegions = craft.entries.section('regions').relatedTo({
    sourceElement: stores,
    field: 'storesRegion'
}) %}

{% for region in relatedRegions %}
    {{ region }}
{% endfor %}
```

good but now I need display all the **Stores** from each **Region**

this is a good example of what I need: https://www.apple.com/retail/storelist/

this is something related with reverse relations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could loop all regions and select their corresponding stores

```
{# you can as well include eager loading here #}
{% for region in craft.entries.section('regions').storesRegion(':notempty:').all() %}
    {% set storesForRegion = craft.entries.section('stores').relatedTo({
        targetElement: region,
        field: 'storesRegion'
    }).all() %}
    {{ region.title }}
    {% for store in storesForRegion %}
        {{ store.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you want to increase your performance you can use [eager loading](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/templating/eager-loading-elements.html) at this point and include `with(['storesRegion'])` to your region `Query`

Comment: works!, I just remove from line2 `.storesRegion(':notempty:')` and add to line6 `{% if storesForRegion|length %}`

Comment: I would not recommend it since it uses deprecated behavior that may be removed but if you feel good with it ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I just modify a little your code because yours won't display anything, no errors but no stores, white page, check the working code. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Working Code:

`{% for region in craft.entries.section('regions').all() %}
    {% set storesForRegion = craft.entries.section('stores').relatedTo({
        targetElement: region,
        field: 'storesRegion'
    }).all() %}
    {% if storesForRegion|length %}
        {{ region.title }}
        {% for store in storesForRegion %}
            <a href="{{ store.url }}">
                {{ store.title }}
            </a>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}`